# Grails App plugin dependency load order

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Here is a scenario. I have a Grails application that depends on multiple plugins. 
Say App depends on pluginMain, pluginA and pluginB. i.e the application.properties looks like
pluginMain version1
pluginA versionX
pluginB versionX

pluginB is a custom plugin written by me. 
pluginA is a 3rd party plugin. I dont have control over the source code.

both pluginA and pluginB depend on pluginMain.

So when the application loads, depending on the load order of these plugins, Each of pluginA and pluginB try to install pluginMain. The problem is if pluginA loads first it installs version2 of pluginMain and if pluginB loads first then it installs version1 of pluginMain. The app is using version1 of pluginMain. In this case both versions of the pluginMain are installed.

due to multiple versions, the app blows up after starting up. To be precise, it leads to infinite redirects on the login page.

So I was wondering if there is way to specify the load order of the plugins, so that in the app I can say load pluginMain version 1. and all the remaining plugins would use this version of pluginMain.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to force your app to use the desired plugin version in configuration.

[Plugin Dependencies](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.10%20Plugin%20Dependencies)

I had a similar situation but wound up just updating my custom plugins to use the newer version of the depended-on plugin.